# android: remove an item from submenu

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar, submenu

I created list of items in a menu. All these items will be shown in the action bar. Then each item will have a submenu of items again.

Bellow is my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/sceneMenu" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/whiteBalanceList"
    android:icon="@drawable/white_balance_list"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/selWhiteBalance">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/whiteBalanceAuto"
            android:title="Auto" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/whiteBalanceCloudy"
            android:title="Cloudy Daylight" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/whiteBalanceDaylight"
            android:title="Daylight" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/whiteBalanceFluorescent"
            android:title="Fluorescent" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/whiteBalanceIncandescent"
            android:title="Incandescent" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/whiteBalanceShade"
            android:title="Shade" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/whiteBalanceTwilight"
            android:title="Twilight" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/whiteBalanceWarm"
            android:title="Warm Fluorescent" />  
    </menu>
</item>
<item
    android:id="@+id/flashList"
    android:icon="@drawable/flash_list"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/selFlash">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/flashAuto"
            android:title="Auto"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/flashOn"
            android:title="On"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/flashOff"
            android:title="Off"/>
    </menu>
</item>  
</menu>
```

When I try to remove the submenu item (for e.g. I want to remove the item "Auto" under 'White Balance List' submenu) with the following code:

```
menu.getItem(R.id.whiteBalanceList).getSubMenu().removeItem(R.id.whiteBalanceAuto);
```

I get an error of index outOfBoundException because R.id.whiteBalanceList will actually result in random unique number but menu.size() is only 2...

BUT if I do a removeItem instead i.e.

```
menu.removeItem(R.id.whiteBalanceList);
```

It runs perfectly...

any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some work-around to solve the problem in the end.
Below is my code:

```
MenuItem whiteMenu = null;
for (int i = 0; i < menu.size(); i++) {
    if (menu.getItem(i).getItemId() == R.id.whiteBalanceList) {
        whiteMenu = menu.getItem(i);
        break;
    }
}
if (whiteMenu != null)
    checkWhiteBalance(whiteList, whiteMenu.getSubMenu());

private void checkWhiteBalance(List<String> list, Menu menu) {
    if (!list.contains(Camera.Parameters.WHITE_BALANCE_AUTO))
        menu.removeItem(R.id.whiteBalanceAuto);
    if (!list.contains(Camera.Parameters.WHITE_BALANCE_CLOUDY_DAYLIGHT))
        menu.removeItem(R.id.whiteBalanceCloudy);
    if (!list.contains(Camera.Parameters.WHITE_BALANCE_DAYLIGHT))
        menu.removeItem(R.id.whiteBalanceDaylight);
    if (!list.contains(Camera.Parameters.WHITE_BALANCE_FLUORESCENT))
        menu.removeItem(R.id.whiteBalanceFluorescent);
    if (!list.contains(Camera.Parameters.WHITE_BALANCE_INCANDESCENT))
        menu.removeItem(R.id.whiteBalanceIncandescent);
    if (!list.contains(Camera.Parameters.WHITE_BALANCE_SHADE))
        menu.removeItem(R.id.whiteBalanceShade);
    if (!list.contains(Camera.Parameters.WHITE_BALANCE_TWILIGHT))
        menu.removeItem(R.id.whiteBalanceTwilight);
    if (!list.contains(Camera.Parameters.WHITE_BALANCE_WARM_FLUORESCENT))
        menu.removeItem(R.id.whiteBalanceWarm);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess you had to use 'findItem' instead of 'getItem' like

```
menu.findItem(R.id.whiteBalanceList).getSubMenu().removeItem(R.id.whiteBalanceAuto);
```

I would put more checks for NULL as well, just in case :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because your subMenus don't have any ID so that they can be pointed by your project R.java. Try givinh ID to your submenus also, then try again.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/sceneMenu" >

<item
android:id="@+id/whiteBalanceList"
android:icon="@drawable/white_balance_list"
android:showAsAction="always"
android:title="@string/selWhiteBalance">
<menu 
    android:id="@+id/whiteSubMenu">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/whiteBalanceAuto"
        android:title="Auto" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/whiteBalanceCloudy"
        android:title="Cloudy Daylight" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/whiteBalanceDaylight"
        android:title="Daylight" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/whiteBalanceFluorescent"
        android:title="Fluorescent" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/whiteBalanceIncandescent"
        android:title="Incandescent" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/whiteBalanceShade"
        android:title="Shade" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/whiteBalanceTwilight"
        android:title="Twilight" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/whiteBalanceWarm"
        android:title="Warm Fluorescent" />  
</menu>
</item>
<item
android:id="@+id/flashList"
android:icon="@drawable/flash_list"
android:showAsAction="always"
android:title="@string/selFlash">
<menu
    android:id="@+id/flashSubMenu">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/flashAuto"
        android:title="Auto"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/flashOn"
        android:title="On"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/flashOff"
        android:title="Off"/>
</menu>
</item>  
</menu>
```

Also, it could be because use call remove method before menu inflated?
Could you give your java code also?

Comment: Hmmmm I don't think so... Since the error is thrown by menu.getItem(R.id.whiteBalanceList) which means I was trying to get the item from the first-level menu.. But will try if ur suggestion works! Will try it on Monday! Thanks for the suggestion. will let you know again :)

Comment: I've tried adding id to the submenu and still doesn't work. But I got my apps running okay already with some work-around. will post the answer soon. Thanks for helping mate!